# Соединить два числа в одно на C

Tags: c++, c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы

У меня есть два массива:

```
long long ** a = (long long**)malloc(size * size * sizeof(long long));
long long ** b = (long long**)malloc(size * size * sizeof(long long));
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы каждые четыре элемента из массива *a* сливались в один элемент массива *b* не преобразовывая чисел в строки:

```cpp
a[0] = 10;
a[1] = 12;
a[2] = 3;
a[3] = 8944;

b[0] = 101238944;
```

Нагуглить не смог (или не понял, как это сделать)

Comment: так у вас числа идут строками что ли?

Comment: если да, то просто сканкатенируйте их, если нет, то перевидите в строки и сканкатенируйте

Comment: Я же написал, без строк

Comment: ну а я вам написал: если это не строки, то переведите в строки. Почему вам нужно именно без строк?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch ненужно переводить в строки это нерационально. Лучше воспользоваться математикой.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков несоглашусь: сама задача конкатенации чисел - далека от математики. Да можно домнажать на 10 * n, но разве это рациональнее чем сконкатенировать в качестве строк? Прям как по условию

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Это обычная задача из курса дискретной математики. И через математику однозначно лучше. Операции со строками выполняются гораздо дольше, чем с несколькими числами.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков не спорю про то что дольше и быстрее просто хочу выяснить для чего подобная конкатенация чисел может пригодится? Всмысле вот вы где применяли подобное?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Понятия не имею где. Мне нигде, больше использую строки, хендлы, таблицы и вектора.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков подобное задание о конкатенации чисел сродни заданию прапорщика: капац отсюда и до обеда а я пойду узнаю где надо. В задании явно описана строковая конкатенация (числа в математике не конкатенируются!!!), но требуется сделал через числа. Не то чтобы это было сложно - это просто бесполезно, потому что, как я писал выше: числа не конкатенируются. Нет такой операции в математике

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch Есть задачи о системах счисления, и они относятся именно к математике.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, imho это задание на сообразительность от педагога-энтузиаста-... (оставшиеся эпитеты добавьте сами)

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков ну раз задача относится к математике, то вас не затруднит привести пример уравнения, теоремы да чего угодно где требуется конкатенация чисел. Я за всю свою жизнь не видел ничего подобного - может вы меня удивите))

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков просто вопрос: вы думаете, что в таком представлении как это фигурирует в задаче, можно использовать арифметические операции? И да, конкатенации я там так и не увидел)

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch значит надо смотреть. Она там есть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ловите образец, под свои массивы сами доделайте.

```
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned long long
cdigs (unsigned long long r, unsigned long long v, int level)
{
  if (v == 0)
    return level ? r : r * 10;
  char d = v % 10;
  return cdigs(r, v / 10, ++level) * 10 + d;
}


int
main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  unsigned long long a[8] = {10, 201, 3001, 4001, 1, 0, 2, 30}, t, b[2];

  for (int i = 0, j = 0; j < 2; j++, i += 4) {
    t = cdigs(0, a[i], 0);
    t = cdigs(t, a[i + 1], 0);
    t = cdigs(t, a[i + 2], 0);
    b[j] = cdigs(t, a[i + 3], 0);
  }
  
  /* или можно даже так ...
    b[0] = cdigs(cdigs(cdigs(cdigs(0, a[0], 0), a[1], 0), a[2], 0), a[3], 0);
  */
  printf("%llu %llu\n", b[0], b[1]);
}
```

Т.е. мы в рекурсии разбиваем число на десятичные цифры, а возвращаясь из нее добавляем их к результату.
(практически так же вы поступаете, когда

1. разбираете число на цифры для печати;
2. читая цифры, получаете из них число
   только в этом случае начальное значение числа не 0, а уже накопленная ранее комбинация цифр)

Answer (score 0):

Надо просто измерить длину чисел и домножить на 10^X.

```
auto l1 = quick_pow10(numDigits(a[1]));
auto l2 = quick_pow10(numDigits(a[2]));
auto l3 = quick_pow10(numDigits(a[3]));
b[0] = ((a[0] * l1 + a[1]) * l2 + a[2]) * l3 + a[3];
```

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1489830/efficient-way-to-determine-number-of-digits-in-an-integer

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18581560/any-way-faster-than-pow-to-compute-an-integer-power-of-10-in-c